# How to pass an additional parameter to graffle.js

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I'm trying to pass an additional parameter to the graffle's connection function so that I can draw a connection with/without an arrow at the end of the line based on that new parameter.

To draw a connection, I normally do something like :

```
connections.push(paper.connection(obj1, obj2, "#000"));
```

Now I want to add this new parameter this way:

```
connections.push(paper.connection(condCol, ret, "#000",true));
```

But the parameter is always `undefined`

This is how I've changed the connection function:

```
Raphael.fn.connection = function (obj1, obj2, line, bg, addArrow) {

  //...

  if (line && line.line) {
      //...
    } else {
        // based on the 'addArrow' parameter I can figure out 
        // whether I should put an arrow at the end of the line or not
        var settings;
        if (addArrow) {
            //If addArrow was true, draw a arrow at the end of the line
            settings = { "stroke": color, fill: "none", 'stroke-width': 2, 'arrow-end': 'block-midium-midium' };
        }
        else {
             //If addArrow was false, just draw a line
            settings = { "stroke": color, fill: "none", 'stroke-width': 2 };
        }
        return {
            bg: bg && bg.split && this.path(path).attr({ stroke: bg.split("|")[0], fill: "none", "stroke-width": bg.split("|")[1] || 3 }),
            line: this.path(path).attr(settings), //use the settings
            from: obj1,
            to: obj2
        };
    }

}
```

Do you have any idea why this isn't working??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your new `connection()` function takes five parameters.  You are only passing it four.  That's why `addArray` is undefined.  The `true` value you are passing is going into the `bg` parameter.  Try calling like this:

```
connections.push(paper.connection(condCol, ret, "#000", null, true));
```

Comment: What difference does it make to pass `null` or empty string for the `bg` parameter?

Comment: In this case it doesn't matter because of the way the code is testing whether b is present.  An empty string in JS is treated as false when converted to a boolean.  So is a null.  But other code may be doing the test another way.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys, I didn't notice those were optional parameters. 
The solution was straightforward. 
I just change the definition of the method  like this:

```
Raphael.fn.connection = function (obj1, obj2, line, bg, addArrow) {

}
```

And call the function, leaving out the fourth parameter:

```
connections.push(paper.connection(condCol, ret, "#000","",true));
```

That was it.